# How can I append a text file's variables values in the corresponding index of a 2D array/list?

Tags: python

Code:

```
    opener = open("gymclub.txt", "r")
    reader = opener.readline()
    listPressups = [["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",]]
    while reader!="":
        splitting=reader.split(",")
        name = splitting[0]
        press_ups = splitting[1]
        pull_ups = splitting[2]
        reader = opener.readline()
        for x in range(1,12):
            listPressups[0][x].append(int(press_ups))
    listPressups.sort(reverse=True)
    print(listPressups)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nutzer/Desktop/Python/practice_NEA/index.py", line 36, in <module>
    listPressups[0][x].append(int(press_ups))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Desired Output:

```
[["",75],["",74],["",73],["",67],["",66],["",58],["",45],["",33],["",30],["",25],["",10],["",8]]
```

What method can I use to reach my desired output?

The text file I used:

[image]

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your program depends on external input that you failed to provide (images are not acceptable).  Unless you know that your problem involves that input, replace it with a hard-coded list.

Comment: You also failed to trace your program's operation.  For instance, why do you append each input element to your nested list (*not* an array) twelve times?

Comment: Your greatest problem is that you've tried to code the entire program at once, without testing the pieces as you go.  You now have multiple problems to fix -- and unless you get them *all*, your current program will produce *no* useful output.  Instead, test intermediate stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
opener = open("gymclub.txt", "r")
listPressups = []
for line in opener.readlines():
    press_ups = int(line.split(",")[1])
    listPressups.append(["", press_ups])
listPressups.sort(reverse=True)
opener.close()
print(listPressups)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
listPressups[0][x].append(int(press_ups))
```

It should be

```
listPressups[x][1].append(int(press_ups))
```

Comment: I tried this, I got the same error, list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You could just start with an empty array, here: `listPressups` and append with just a `while loop` as shown below.

```
opener = open("gymclub.txt", "r")
reader = opener.readline()
#listPressups = [["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",],["",]]
listPressups = []
while reader!="":
    splitting=reader.split(",")
    name = splitting[0]
    press_ups = splitting[1]
    pull_ups = splitting[2]
    reader = opener.readline()
    listPressups.append(["",int(press_ups)]) #Here we append an empty string with each value
listPressups.sort(reverse=True)
print(listPressups)
```